# Python/Django - list index out of range for function

Tags: python, django

I have a function that gets a users history and puts it in a breadcrumb, and im trying to make that breadcrumb look better by having a display. so my function should be able to return a nice readable url instead of /service/site/7 it will give "Site UK" or "Showroom - Italy" as the breadcrumb.

however as soon as i load pages without (i presume) enough items i get the error "Exception Value: list index out of range"

i thought by using "if list_path[1]:" it would return false if the item does not exist, however it still gives me the error.

i also tried using if "list_path[0] > 0" and "if list_path[0] > 1" it made some pages load but others failed with the same error.

i think its becuase it stores 4 values and runs the script on all four values each time?

Thanks

code:

```
def breadcrumb_history(request):
    history = request.session.get('breadcrumb_history', [])

    # if the last item in the history is the current page, we don't want to add this page to the history
    # if it's not the last item in the history, we do add it
    if len(history) == 0 or history[-1] != request.path:
        url = request.path
        display = ''
        list_path = url.split("/")
        list_path = filter(None,list_path)
        if list_path[0]:
            if list_path[0] != "admin":
                del list_path[0]
        if list_path[1]:
            if list_path[1] == "majorsite":
                list_path[1] = "Major Site"
                site = MajorSiteInfoData.object.values("location").get(pk=list_path[2])
                list_path[2] = site.location
            elif list_path[1] == "showroom":
                showroom = ShowroomConfigData.object.values("location").get(pk=list_path[2])
                list_path[2] = showroom.location

            display = ''.join(list_path)
            display = display.title()
        else:
            display = url.title()
        history.append({"url" : url, "display" : display})

    # if there are more than four items in the history, pop the first one
    if len(history) > 4:
        history.pop(0)

    # save the history to the session
    request.session['breadcrumb_history'] = history

    # return the current breadcrumb
    return {'breadcrumb_history': history}
```

traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://it.internal.com/service/showrooms

Django Version: 1.9.6
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('home.apps.HomeConfig',
 'oncall.apps.OncallConfig',
 'networks.apps.NetworksConfig',
 'maintenance.apps.MaintenanceConfig',
 'service.apps.ServiceConfig',
 'management.apps.ManagementConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'twitter_bootstrap',
 'bootstrap_pagination')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/var/www/infternal/service/views.py" in showroom_list
  41.         'Showrooms': modelShowrooms,

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  97.         return template.render(context, request)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  95.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  204.                 with context.bind_template(self):

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py" in __enter__
  17.             return self.gen.next()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/templates/panel.py" in _request_context_bind_template
  79.             context = processor(self.request)

File "/var/www/infternal/infternal/context_processors.py" in breadcrumb_history
  52.         if list_path[1]:

Exception Type: IndexError at /service/showrooms
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

EDIT:
Sample URLS include:

```
/ (this would be replaced with home)
/majorsite/2 (replaced with "Major Site - HQ" or "Major Site - Warehouse")
/showroom/7 (replaced with "Showroom - London" or "Showroom - Manchester")
```

Comment: Could you please add the entire traceback?

Comment: Why don't  you use a `try - except` block instead of `if`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if list_path[0]:
    if list_path[0] != "admin":
        del list_path[0]  # Here you delete the first element of the list.
                          # Thus `list_path` now equals `['showrooms']`.
                          # and `list_path[1]` doesn't exist anymore.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, not always your urls are as you expect, which involve sometimes not having more than one item in your `list_path` and that could happen due to paths like `/majorsite` or `/admin`, etc... So It could be more accurate doing the replacement following a more safe solution:

```
to_replace = ['majorsite', ...]
replace_with = ['Major Site', ...]

for item in zip(to_replace,replace_with):
    if item[0] in list_path:
        # replace item[0] by item[1] in list_path, since you are sure it is there
        # add additional customizations
```

This is obviously an alternative, you can follow your own way, but in this case you need to be sure, in each case, the array have the expected lenght before asking for an index, and also, the term to replace is there:

```
if len(list_path)>1 and list_path[1]:
    # what you do today
else:
    # handle other cases
```

Also, you code is a bit complex, I'm almost sure there is a simple way to accomplish what you want. If you add some samples of all possible urls you could handle there, and the expected result in each case, you will get some good and simple answer here at SO.

Comment: hi, ive added some sample urls if that helps? Thanks

Answer (score -3):

you should use

```
try: 
    ...
expect IndexError:
    # Handle exception
```

when `list_path` have nothing

Comment: This is right, however it does not explain why `list_path[1]` throws IndexError, while `list_path` is supposed to be `['service', 'showrooms']`.